# how can i show the candidates view under the android soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I'm trying to make a softkeyboard for android but when i edit the candidates view it always shows above the keyboard layout. I tried to set Y position and it moves down but the keyboard layout hides it, although the keyboard is empty and transparent.

I need to show candidates view under the keyboard layout or whatever place, but not above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is not to use the candidate view.  In fact we didn't use it at Swype at all-  we didn't like some of the built in behaviors.  Just return a null candidate view in onCreateCandidateView.  Then in your main keyboard layout, add a view to use for candidates below the keyboard and use that as the candidate view.

Comment: Hi, Its a bit late, what are the built in behaviors that were a problem? if you still remember

Comment: The big thing was that if the candidate view appeared or disappeared it would cause the application above the app to  resize (assuming the soft input mode was adjustResize).  This caused a delay and a performance hit as the app had onMeasure and onLayout called on its root view, and could cause a user to hit the wrong button if they went to touch the app.  It also had a timing bug where it would cause an infinite loop of resizing causing the app to bounce up and down.  We decided just never to hide it to avoid that, at which time treating it as a separate view gave us no advantage.